# Example of command query separation pattern

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, domain-driven-design

I am trying to find an example of the command query separation pattern, but I am not able to find one. I am interested if I could use it to return entities that are a part of the composite object in the repository layer? I am trying to apply some DDD.

Comment: I don't think of it as a pattern, but as a concept.  From Wikipedia:

"It states that every method should either be a command that performs an action, or a query that returns data to the caller, but not both."

Comment: You can find an simple example in axon-framework's tuturiol.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about CQRS, have a look at Greg Young's [summary](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/02/16/cqrs-task-based-uis-event-sourcing-agh/).